# django templates - space as thousand separator

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to make my numbers have space as thousand separator and dot as decimal separator, i.e. `100 000.00`, `2 123 324.32`.

I have these settings:

```
USE_L10N = False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ' '
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3
```

this helps with decimal separator, but doesn't help with thousand separator. I still have numbers like 100000.00. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should also set `USE_L10N` to `True`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR

> When USE_L10N is set to True and if this is also set to True, Django will use the values of THOUSAND_SEPARATOR and NUMBER_GROUPING to format numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in django.contrib humanize to make your numbers more readable

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/humanize/

In this case intcomma

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need int type to be return:

in view:

```
@register.filter(name='del_comma')
def del_comma(value):
    if value > 999:
        return str(value // 1000) + ' ' + str(value)[len(str(value // 1000)):]
    return value
```

in template:

```
{{ vacancy.salary_from|del_comma }}
```